# How do I hide some people in Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

All my hangouts are archived, yet Google Hangouts is deciding to show me some arbitrary list of people in there. How do I hide some of them? This list I can see in both gmail and g+.

Comment: From what I can see, that list is automatically generated from the people that you're regularly in contact with, and not just via Hangout. I don't use Hangouts with my wife at all, but I email her a ton, and she's there at the top of my list. It doesn't look there's a way to manually exclude anyone from that list short of blocking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They default that list to 10 people. Unfortunately there is no way to remove the arbitrary list of people. If I understand your observation correctly, it also occurs when you start typing a contact's name in the search box as if you were going to chat/(hangout) with them.

Answer (score 0):

After noticing the above - that you cannot alter your list of Hangout contacts -  I decided to just sign out of Hangouts and revert to old chat since I don't usually do Hangouts. It's not the best fix, but it's a good way not to have to see exes and other jerks you used to chat to!

Comment: Please note that "above" has no context here. Answers can be sorted in a number of ways. If you want to refer to another answer, it's best to link to it.